# How to combine/insert multiple column into one column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue here about SQL, I already search a few sites on 'how to combine column into one one column' and already tried each tips from the helper but I have an error by doing that, the error stated that

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   The multi-part identifier "LOT_LOC_BOND.LOT_ID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   The multi-part identifier "LOC_LOT_IEBT.LOT_ID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   The multi-part identifier "LOT_LOC_MBT.LOT_ID" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   The multi-part identifier "LOT_LOC_SEAL.LOT_ID" could not be bound.

and this is the SQL statement, and fyi I used SQL Server 2014:

```
USE IMS_Location

SELECT TOP(1000)  
    LOT_LOC_BOND.LOT_ID, LOT_LOC_BOND.CheckIn AS BOND_CheckIn, 
    LOT_LOC_BOND.CheckOut As BOND_CheckOut, 
    LOT_LOC_BOND.StatusDesc AS BOND_Status,
    LOT_LOC_IEBT.LOT_ID, LOT_LOC_IEBT.CheckIn AS IEBT_CheckIn,
    LOT_LOC_IEBT.CheckOut AS IEBT_CheckOut, LOT_LOC_IEBT.StatusDesc AS IEBT_Status,
    LOT_LOC_MBT.LOT_ID, LOT_LOC_MBT.CheckIn AS MBT_CheckIn,
    LOT_LOC_MBT.CheckOut AS MBT_CheckOut,
    LOT_LOC_MBT.StatusDesc AS MBT_Status,
    LOT_LOC_SEAL.LOT_ID, LOT_LOC_SEAL.CheckIn AS SEAL_CheckIn,
    LOT_LOC_SEAL.CheckOut AS SEAL_CheckOut,
    LOT_LOC_SEAL.StatusDesc AS SEAL_Status
FROM 
    LOT_LOC_BOND 
LEFT JOIN 
    LOT_LOC_IEBT ON  LOT_LOC_BOND.LOT_ID = LOT_LOC_IEBT.LOT_ID, LOT_LOC_MBT 
LEFT JOIN 
    LOT_LOC_SEAL ON LOT_LOC_MBT.LOT_ID = LOT_LOC_SEAL.LOT_ID

SELECT 
    (LOT_LOC_BOND.LOT_ID + LOC_LOT_IEBT.LOT_ID +
     LOT_LOC_MBT.LOT_ID + LOT_LOC_SEAL.LOT_ID) AS LOT_ID
ORDER BY 
    LOT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

May be what you were trying to do was this; as you probably want to combine the results from multiple columns.

You got error messages because your SELECT syntax was wrong, as there was no FROM to select from.

```
USE IMS_Location

SELECT TOP(1000) 
    (LOT_LOC_BOND.LOT_ID + LOT_LOC_IEBT.LOT_ID +
     LOT_LOC_MBT.LOT_ID + LOT_LOC_SEAL.LOT_ID) AS LOT_ID,
    LOT_LOC_BOND.LOT_ID, LOT_LOC_BOND.CheckIn AS BOND_CheckIn, 
    LOT_LOC_BOND.CheckOut As BOND_CheckOut, 
    LOT_LOC_BOND.StatusDesc AS BOND_Status,
    LOT_LOC_IEBT.LOT_ID, LOT_LOC_IEBT.CheckIn AS IEBT_CheckIn,
    LOT_LOC_IEBT.CheckOut AS IEBT_CheckOut, LOT_LOC_IEBT.StatusDesc AS IEBT_Status,
    LOT_LOC_MBT.LOT_ID, LOT_LOC_MBT.CheckIn AS MBT_CheckIn,
    LOT_LOC_MBT.CheckOut AS MBT_CheckOut,
    LOT_LOC_MBT.StatusDesc AS MBT_Status,
    LOT_LOC_SEAL.LOT_ID, LOT_LOC_SEAL.CheckIn AS SEAL_CheckIn,
    LOT_LOC_SEAL.CheckOut AS SEAL_CheckOut,
    LOT_LOC_SEAL.StatusDesc AS SEAL_Status
FROM 
    LOT_LOC_BOND 
LEFT JOIN 
    LOT_LOC_IEBT ON  LOT_LOC_BOND.LOT_ID = LOT_LOC_IEBT.LOT_ID, LOT_LOC_MBT 
LEFT JOIN 
    LOT_LOC_SEAL ON LOT_LOC_MBT.LOT_ID = LOT_LOC_SEAL.LOT_ID
ORDER BY 
    LOT_ID
```

Comment: I still can't peform it, the error stated tht Incorrect syntax near 'LOT_LOC_BOND'. then I tried put ',' after AS LOT_ID and then another error came out Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "LOC_LOT_IEBT.LOT_ID" could not be bound.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Ambiguous column name 'LOT_ID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Ambiguous column name 'LOT_ID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Ambiguous column name 'LOT_ID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Ambiguous column name 'LOT_ID'.

Comment: do you think it's possible for me to union the LOT_ID  and in the same time left join the other column?